# Why can't I install usb-cam package at RPI3?

Tags: usb-cam, camera, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have installed Raspbian Stretch at my RPi3 and the ros_comm for the ROS Kinetic package (since it was the recommended one from the ros wiki). However, when I try to install any package  the message I receive is "E: unable to locate package" . For example, I type at the terminal "sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-usb-cam" and the message I receive is the above. Any suggestions about what I am doing wrong?

---

Update:

I have followed the instructions from [this site](https://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi):

```
$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall 
$ wstool init src kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298949/why-can%27t-i-install-usb-cam-package-at-rpi3?/) by [pskampas](https://answers.ros.org/users/36715/pskampas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-07-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-29**:
Can you detail exactly which `ros_comm` package you have installed? What is the exact package name?

I'm wondering whether you're running into [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

**Comment by [pskampas](https://answers.ros.org/users/36715/pskampas/) on 2018-07-29**:
I have followed the instructions from this site: https://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Kinetic%20on%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi

"$ rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro kinetic --deps --wet-only --tar > kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall
$ wstool init src kinetic-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall"

**Comment by [lusim](https://answers.ros.org/users/37146/lusim/) on 2018-08-24**:
I am dealing with the same problem. Could you find any solution?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
@lusim: which problem? The two answers already explain that if you've installed ROS from sources, you cannot use `apt-get` as the OP tries to do. One of the answers then goes on to detail how to start installing a pkg from sources (but the description is incomplete, see #q252478). If you're ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-24**:
.. experiencing specific problems with locating or building the pkg you're trying to install, please post a new question.

**Comment by [lusim](https://answers.ros.org/users/37146/lusim/) on 2018-08-27**:
ok thank you. But is there another way to install ROS on a Raspberry Pi 3? I already tried some ways to install it but installing it from source was the only thing working for me. Having an alternative installation of ROS would actually solve the described problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-27**:
Unfortunately I'm not an RPi user, so I can't really suggest anything.

Binary pkgs for ARM architectures are built for ARMv7 (hard-float) Ubuntu and ARMv8 Debian and Ubuntu. Perhaps that is something you can work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you installed everything from source, then you cannot use `apt` to install new packages.

You'll have to create an overlay workspace, place the sources of the new package in your new workspace, source your old workspace and then build your new workspace.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn is right
if you have successfully installed the ROS then you can install the `usb_cam` by cloning the package from git.

1. Create a catkin workspace by following the [process here](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace)
2. Clone the package from [GitHub](https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam)

   `git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/usb_cam.git`
3. Build and source your workspace and that's it.

---

Originally posted by [simbha](https://answers.ros.org/users/29493/simbha/) with karma: 241 on 2018-07-31

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1